# Preventing OnClientClick to newtab of Button to trigger Other clicks on the page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using a `Button` in `Web form` and `onclick` event should open a report in new tab. I am using `onclientclick` property of `Button` but it enables all the other `Button` or `Radio Button` to redirect in new tab. How to prevent this.

Comment: Please show us the javascript code for the button, since you're using OnClientClick.

Comment: btprint.OnClientClick = "aspnetForm.target='_blank'";
Response.Redirect("yojna4only.aspx");

Comment: I'm sorry, but this just isn't enough to go on. I've no clue why clicking radiobuttons would suddenly create a new tab etc.

Comment: actually the (onclientclick="aspnetForm='_blank'") event triggers all the click in the form to open in the new tab. Thus any other click on the form will also be redirected in new tab

Comment: The only thing I can think of that does that, is if you've added that OnClientClick event to the body instead of the button =/

Comment: @Destrictor i didnt underastand ur comment using OnClientClick event on body. Will u please elaborate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code on Button click instead of OnClientClick

```
btnPrint.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.open('yourpage.aspx'); return false;");
```

Comment: It worked but i cant use that because i am sending query string with the (Response.Redirect)

Comment: @Himanshu just use `btnPrint.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.open('" + yourpage + "'); return false;");` since you're doing this in codebehind anyways

Answer (score 0):

If you enable OnClientClick to open in a new tab then you must revert this functionallity back after the window was opened.

You've got 2 options

1. on click any other button on the window
2. setTimeout() after few moments

Use this function / code within:

```
function ResetTarget() {
   window.document.forms[0].target = '';
}
```